# Is there such a thing as decreasing wireless range when multiple users are on the network at the same time?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, router

Basically the title. I recently realized, if my laptop was connected to the internet through WiFi, it seems to decrease the range of another computer in the house, quite far away from the router, but if I turnoff my WiFi, the range seems to "increase", allowing the other computer to connect from its position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can decrease the range.   One of the important things in defining the range of a wireless device is the "signal to noise" ratio - the higher the signal to noise, the further away you can detect the signal and the faster it works.

When your device is transmitting its raising the noise floor and worstening the connection.

You can think about it this way - In a quiet room 2 people can whisper to each other and communicate.   Turn on a loud television (or radio or whatever) and they can no longer whisper to each other.  WIFI works the same way, only at a higher frequency, and your laptop is making the noise of the television.

Comment: Does the usage of internet have any major influence on the signal strength as well?, or does it solely depend on just connecting to the WiFi? Another question, will using a wired connection to the router fix this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the usage of the Internet can have amajor influence on signal strength - going back to my analogy, using the Internet is like turning up the volume on the TV.    A wired connection will fix the issue you described.   Moving the router to a more central spot may also mitigate some of the problems (but a wired connection is almost always a better performing option)